# Javascript/Jquery width of a graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently having trouble making my horizontal bar graph width. the current problem is that i don't know how my "" and '' should be placed so that the `obj.sightingCount` can be used as a width in the `buildGraph` function.

css:

```
div.bar {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 5px;
        background-color: blue;            
        }
    div.year {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

jQuery/javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: "api/UFOSightings",
        method: "GET",
        timeout: 10000,            
        success: buildGraph,
        error: myError  
    });


    function myError(data) {
    }

    function buildGraph(data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
            $('#graph').append('<div><div class="year">' + obj.sightingYear + '</div><div class="bar" style= width: "obj.sightingCount%;" >' + obj.sightingCount + '</div></div>');
        })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work for you

```
function buildGraph(data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, obj) {
        $('#graph').append('<div><div class="year">' + obj.sightingYear + '</div><div class="bar" style="width:'+ obj.sightingCount + '%;" >' + obj.sightingCount + '</div></div>');
    });
}
```